# Is it possible to pass an anonymous object as argument of an RMI method?

Tags: java, rmi, anonymous-class

I am trying to invoke a remote method via RMI that takes 1 argument of type `MyData`, which is an interface known in both server side and client side.

In my client class `MyClass`, I created an anonymous object of type `MyData`, and passed it to the remote method, and got an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at wt.method.RemoteMethodServer.invoke(RemoteMethodServer.java:795)
    at 
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass$1 (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

Question: Must I use an **implementation** of the interface `MyData` to pass RMI method argument? That **implementation** is known on both server and client sides.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be know to your registry.

Comment: @PeterLawrey There is no evidence here that the Registry is involved, and if the client is calling a remote method it must already have done a successful Registry lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if:

1. The class is deployed to the CLASSPATH of the peer, or available via the codebase feature, *and*
2. The class within which it is defined is `Serializable`, *and*
3. You realize and accept that the outer class instance will be sent along with the anonymous class, because it's an inner class and has a reference to its outer class, and therefore that the outer class also has to be deployed to the peer or available via the codebase feature.

(2) May not be true, and may not need to be true for any reason other than this, and (3) is very likely to be untrue, as it is very likely to be a client-only class that is none of the server's business.

Don't do this. There is no advantage, and several disadvantages. Use an outer or static class.